# Подскажите, с каким подарком в гости к предложению прийти: с двоеточием или тире?

Tags: двоеточие-тире

`Больше нечего ловить: всë, что надо, я поймал.`

`Больше нечего ловить — всë, что надо, я поймал.`

В теории и тот и тот подарок подойдëт. Но какой, по вашему мнению, лучше? Кажется, тире.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбор варианта зависит **от контекста:**

(1) *А что здесь еще делать? Больше нечего ловить: **всë, что надо, я поймал.***

**Пояснительная** конструкция (указание причины), двоеточие, интонационное предупреждение.

(2) *Больше нечего ловить — **всë, что надо, я поймал**. Пойду домой.*

**Присоединительная** конструкция (пауза меньше).